# Solve $\lambda u_t+u_x=-u$ with $x,t > 0$ and $u(x,0)=0$ and $u(0,t)=\sinh{t}$ using method of characteristics

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I am asked to solve the following PDE using the method of characteristics:

$\lambda u_t+u_x=-u$ with $x,t > 0$ and $u(x,0)=0$ and $u(0,t)=\sinh{t}$

---

So I get (I use q instead of t given that t is already used): 
$t_q=\lambda$ with $t(0,s)=s$ so $t(q)=\lambda q + s$ 

$x_q=1$ with $x(0,s)=0$ so $x(q)=q+0$
and 
$u_q=-u$ with $u(0,s)=0$ so $u(q)=e^{-q}-1$ (?) 
Using $u(0,t)=\sinh{t}$, we get $u(q,t)=e^{-q}-1+\sinh{t}$ (?)

We also know that $q=x$ thus $s=t-\lambda x$, using the first and second ODEs. So our final result is $u(x,t)=e^{-x}-1+\sinh{t}$.

Now, I am used to have only one initial condition, not two of them. (Also, I don't see why they use $t$ while we generally use $y$ instead.) So I am not sure if this is really correct, and would like your review.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I can't imagine that the final answer doesn't have a $\lambda$ in it. Have you plugged your answer into the original PDE to see if it's satisfied?

Comment: @AdrianKeister Uhm yeah you're right, it does not satsify the PDE. But I don't really see how to proceed otherwise -_-

Comment: Do you have to use characteristics? I'd far rather start with separation of variables. In this case, you're going to have to do Fourier analysis to obtain the $\sinh(t)$ initial condition. But I think it's possible.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Well, this is an old exam question with no solutions (sadly). And the question says that we should use the method of characteristics to solve it. That's why I am a bit troubled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lambda u_t+u_x=-u \quad\text{with}\quad \begin{cases} x,t > 0 \\ u(x,0)=0 \\ u(0,t)=\sinh{t}\end{cases}$$
Charpit-Lagrange system of characteristic equations :
$$\frac{dt}{\lambda}=\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{du}{-u}$$
First characteristic equation from $\frac{dt}{\lambda}=\frac{dx}{1}$ :
$$t-\lambda x=c_1$$
Second characteristic equation from $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{du}{-u}$ :
$$ue^x=c_2$$
General solution on the form of implicit equation $c_2=F(c_1)=ue^x=F(t-\lambda x)$ :
$$u=e^{-x}F(t-\lambda x)$$
The function $F(X)$ is arbitrary, to be determined according to the specified conditions.

Boundary condition : $u(0,t>0)=\sinh(t)=e^0F(t-0)$ determines the function $$F(X)=\sinh(X) \qquad X>0$$

Initial condition : $u(x>0,0)=0=e^{-x}F(-\lambda x)$ determines the function $$F(X)=0\quad\begin{cases} X>0 \text{ if } \lambda <0 \\ X<0 \text{ if } \lambda >0 \end{cases}$$

All together $F(X)$ is a piecewise function , excluding the case $\lambda<0$.
$$F(X)=\begin{cases} \sinh(X) && X>0 \\0 && X<0\end{cases}$$
In the general solution $X=t-\lambda x$ thus :
$$u(x,t)=\begin{cases} e^{-x}\sinh(t-\lambda x) && t>\lambda x \\0 && t<\lambda x\end{cases}\qquad x,t,\lambda>0$$

[image]

ADDITION, in order to answer to a comment.

Copy from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics

[image]

Comment: May I ask you if my question can already be found somewhere on the internet ? I mean, you used an image at the end, so probably you have found the image somewhere. Because before asking here, I searched on the web but did not find something.

Comment: Also, when is it better to use the Charpit-Lagrange system instead of the traditional parametrisation that I tried to use in my attempt ? And could we also try to express $c_1$ in terms of $c_2$ instead of the opposite ? Would it change anything at the end ?

Comment: The image doesn't come from elsewhere. I draw it with ms-paint especially to complete my answer.

The system $\quad\frac{dt}{\lambda}=\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{du}{-u}=ds\quad$is another manner to write $\begin{cases}dt=\lambda\: ds \\dx=ds\\ du=-u\:ds\end{cases}$. 

I don't see any basic difference with the parametric presentation.

Comment: See the addition to my main answer.

Comment: Instead of $c_2=F(c_1)$ you can equivalently use $c_1=G(c_2)$ where $F$ and $G$ are arbitrary functions, but related (one is the inverse of the other). Of course this changes the calculus in taking account of the conditions but the final result is the same.. In fact the implicit equation is $\Phi(c_1 , c_2)=0$ where $\Phi$ is an arbitrary function of two variables. The two above simplified forms are possible when the implicit equation is solvable with respect to one of the variables $c_1$ or $c_2$.

Comment: Last question: "The two above simplified forms are possible when the implicit equation is solvable with respect to one of the variables". Does this have any link with the transversality condition for PDE ?

Comment: This is another manner to say that if an equation $\Phi(X,Y)=0$ is solvable for $X$ the result is $X=F(Y)$, nothing more.